# Map over API data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map over an API that is set up like the following picture:
[image]

Currently my code is set up so that I can call the headline, source, and image of which ever number I choose. I.e. if i do

```
const headline = res.data[0]['headline'];
this.setState({ headline })
```

I can get the first headline, under the name '0'

```
const headline = res.data[1]['headline'];
this.setState({ headline })
```

Then I can get the second headline, under the name '1'.

But rather than writing the same code 5-10 times, I am trying map through it so that I can return each version sliced to how many I want. I do not know how to setup the syntax, as I thought I would do something like:

```
<h1>
{
res.data.length && res.data.map(data =>  (
{data.headline}
))
}
</h1>
```

I got res.data is not defined as I did this in the return and not under getStock, not sure how to set this up.

News.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

export class News extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            headline: "",
            source: "",
            image: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getStock();
    }

    getStock() {
        const API_KEY = '*********************';
        const API_CALL = `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/news?token=${API_KEY}`;
        axios.get(API_CALL)
        .then(res => {
            const headline = res.data[1]['headline'];
            this.setState({ headline })

            const source = res.data[1]['source'];
            this.setState({ source })

            const image = res.data[1]['image'];
            this.setState({ image })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.headline} </h1>
                <p>{this.state.source}</p>
                <img src={this.state.image} alt="img" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default News
```

Answer (score 2):

You fist approach using `.map` was right you just need to make sure to check if `res` exists.

```
res && res.data.length && res.data.map(data =>  ...
```

Comment: The problem is that `res` is contained in `getStock`, so @Caleb would need to change his state to accept the response and then use the response from state in `render`

Comment: is it something like this under getStock: ```const res = res;
            this.setState(res)```. That code returns and error but right idea maybe

Comment: @EliasSchablowski If you could give me an example code that would be greatly helpful, as I am still struggling with this.

Comment: @Caleb https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dubinsky-pzj23?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in the code under return the call has an error from being incomplete. How do I write that I tried ```<h1>{this.state.map(news) => {this.state.news.headline})</h1>``` still getting errors though

Comment: @EliasSchablowski in the code under return the call has an error from being incomplete. How do I write that I tried <h1>{this.state.map(news) => {this.state.news.headline})</h1> still getting errors though

Comment: just remove that parentheses `)` `<h1>{ this.state.map(news => news.headline) }</h1>`

Comment: @GabrielDonadelDall'Agnol hello, sorry for the late response, I never received a notification, but I am receiving an error 'this.state.map is not a function'